# Notepad++ retain only repeated part

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ and regex, I wish to retain a portion of data that repeats multiple times in a single file.

```
Block Start

some code
some code
some code

Block End

some other code
some other code
some other code

Block Start

some code
some code
some code

Block End
```

`Block Start` to `Block End`is the portion that i want to retain, while others i want to delete. Tried some myself but did not work. some help maybe? thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `Tried some myself but did not work , post your attempts.`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Block End)|.(?!(?:(?!\bBlock Start)[\s\S])*\bBlock End)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1` or `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/54